# Relocation overflow when performing bitwise AND (SPARC Assembly)?

Tags: gcc, assembly, bitmask, sparc, bitwise-and

I am trying to perform a bitwise AND on a register, as a bitmask to remove the most significant bit (which happens to be bit 16 when counting from 0). However, when I try to compile my code using gcc, it gives me the following error messages:

Assembler messages:
19: Error: relocation overflow

My guess is that this has something to do with the size of the bit mask I am applying, because when I perform the AND with two registers containing small numbers I don't encounter the same error. The code itself looks like,

```
.global main
main:
save    %sp, -96, %sp

clr %l1
clr     %l2
set 0xffff, %l0
set 0xaaaa8c01, %l4
set 0xff001234, %l5
set 0x13579bdf, %l6
set 0xc8b4ae32, %l7
srl %l4, 31, %l1    
srl %l0, 15, %l2
xor %l1, %l2, %l1
and %l1, 0x1, %l1
sll %l0, 1, %l0
add %l0, %l1, %l0
and %l0, 0xffff, %l0


mov 1, %g1
ta  0
```

If anyone could offer some insight on how to solve this problem it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

badPanda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant bit is bit 15 (in a 16-bit integer, when bits are zero based).

Comment: This is for a 32 bit integer. What I meant was that the bits from 17 onwards hold zeros (and should always hold zeros) in this particular problem. Perhaps MSB was not the correct terminology?

Comment: Do you mean 16-31 hold zeros? Which are the most significant 16 bits in a 32 bit integer. I am wondering if you are just experiencing register overflow due to one of those srl/sll instructions.

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant. Sorry for the confusion (I am just learning). All of the srl/sll instructions compile and work as intended when I run them, but the last line (add %l0, 0xffff, %l0) will not.

Comment: @badpanda as I recall, the SPARC opcodes support immidiate values up to 10 or 12 bits. If you need more, use the `load high` instruction (can't recall the exact mnemonic).

Comment: Thanks ruslik, this ended up being the problem.